# Create html element for every element in array (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I have Angular component

Here is code

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-testcomponent',
  templateUrl: './testcomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testcomponent.component.scss']
})
export class TestcomponentComponent implements OnInit {

  version: string = environment.version;
  error: string;
  searchForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient
    ) {
    this.createForm();
   }

  ngOnInit() {}

  search() {
    this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query='+this.searchForm.value.jokevalue ).subscribe(
    data => [
      console.log(data)
    ])
  }

  private createForm() {
    this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      jokevalue: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }
}
```

Function `search()` is related to get values from API and make HTML markup for every element in the array on submit button. Here is template HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <form class="form-inline" (ngSubmit)="search()" [formGroup]="searchForm" novalidate>
      <label for="text">Enter value:</label>
      <input formControlName="jokevalue" style="margin-left:20px;" type="text" class="form-control" id="email">
      <button style="margin-left:20px;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Getting array is done and here is an array of response

> {
>     "category": null,
>     "icon_url": "https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png",
>     "id": "cq6hLP0ETeW4VSrm7SYg5A",
>     "url": "https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/cq6hLP0ETeW4VSrm7SYg5A",
>     "value": "Chuck Norris knows WAZZZUP!"
>   }

So now I need to loop from the array(it can have more than one element) and create HTML markup for every element

For example this

```
<div>
<p>Number of array element</p>
<p>"value"</p>
</div>
```

I try to do it like this

```
 data => [
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  }
])
```

But seems it not right.

How I can solve my problem.

Thank's

Answer (score 9):

expose your data in your component source:

```
  public jokes: any[]; //or create an interface instead of using "any" for "strong" typing support

  search() {
    this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query='+this.searchForm.value.jokevalue ).subscribe(
    data => [
      console.log(data)
      this.jokes = data;
    ])
  }
```

use an [*ngFor](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) in your component template to [bind](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview) to your data:

```
<div *ngFor="let joke of jokes">
    <p>{{joke.category}}</p>
    <p>{{joke.value}}</p>
</div>
```

---

**update for comments around not using an array:**

expose your data in your component source:

```
  public joke: any; //or create an interface instead of using "any" for "strong" typing support

  search() {
    this.http.get('https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query='+this.searchForm.value.jokevalue ).subscribe(
    data => [
      console.log(data)
      this.joke = data;
    ])
  }
```

component template:

```
<div>
    <p>{{joke.category}}</p>
    <p>{{joke.value}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: is it like: data => {
      console.log(data)
      this.jokes = data;
    })

Comment: yeah, but I get error
`Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?`

Comment: So maybe Object instead of any?

Comment: looks like your API is returning a single JSON object, not an array of objects.  An array would be enclosed in []

Comment: I would change the API code to return an array instead of the single object it is currently returning, since you said the API is returning an array, and that's what makes sense.  If you only have a single object using *ngFor wouldn't apply.

Comment: I can chang API, because it's not mine. 

So how I can make it works with object?

Comment: Yeah, it works. But if I make for example request on submit.

like this `(ngSubmit)="search()"` I need to append this markup to template div, and your code will mot works

Comment: That should be taken care of automatically because of the data binding, can you create a http://plnkr.co/ and link to it showing the issue?